# Angular 2 - Multiple Component doesn't work

Tags: angular

I learned angular 2, but I can't do a multiple component, for exemple I try this and is doesen't work :

app.module.ts :

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, TestComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent  {}
```

test.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html'
})

export class TestComponent {}
```

app.component.html :

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

test.component.html :

```
<h2>test</h2>
```

Comment: Can you show us, what you did in `./app.component.html`? It would work if you have specified `test` inside `AppComponent` html..

Comment: Do you want your test component to display inside your app component? If so, add `<test></test>` to `app.component.html`

Answer (score 1):

You have to "call" the test component from the app.

And in Angular 2, it is done with html tag selectors.

If you add  `<test></test>`

in app.component.html, it should render the test component.